# Account management

Tags: support, user-accounts

What steps are needed to cancel one's account and annonymize the existing content?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It has crossed my mind recently that, depending on this site's trajectory, I might in some future point not want to have my name associated with it. So I am checking what would be my options to dissociate from it in such eventuality.

Comment: Hopefully the crackpots won't get that bad ;). But what's the problem with just stopping posting if that happens?

Comment: Yeah, maybe that's good enough, just trying to educate myself about the options.

Comment: This was done for a ex-user known as Rich B. on the original site. It required the intervention of the team.

Comment: @dmckee: I think you're thinking of mmyers. Easy mistake to make, considering the account is now *anonymous*. You certainly aren't thinking of Neil Butterworth though, since no such person exists.

Comment: @Hiatus: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want your name associated with the site, just change your display name. That can always be done from your profile.

In the meantime, you can always offer your feedback and try to keep the site from going in a direction you don't like.

Comment: Thanks David. I offered my feedback, and it may just be that we have fundamental differences on the purpose of the site and how it is managed. I am confused for example on why the moderators chose to overturn the community's judgement on closing the question we discussed yesterday. I think I will just leave it to you guys steering the site where you want it to go, I think I already made my opinion abundantly clear.

Comment: @Moshe: Well perhaps. For this particular incident you should ask mbq about it, since he's the one who reopened the question. (I'm not sure if he saw the meta question you'd posted yesterday) Hopefully you understand that we can't always act according to every bit of feedback we get, but it does _not_ mean your concerns carry no weight.

Comment: @David, thanks. Any particular incident is insignificant by itself. But, there is a policy issue on how aggressive you want to be on quality control, and it is really up to you moderators to discuss it and decide for yourselves. In my mind any internet forum above a certain size will have to do some weeding, I saw it when I had a blog. So, sooner or later you'd have to deal with this issue, one way or another.

Comment: I deleted the discussion on the situation at Math Overflow because, well, it's just long. That could go on in the chat room but not here.

Comment: And along with it my criticisms of how people are acting here, apparently!

Comment: Well that can be brought up elsewhere, if it bothers you enough. Remember that comments are transient.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your account deleted by asking the moderators in chat for example, or you can set your user name as "please delete me".

For example try typing "please delete me" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users).

Answer (score 1):

You can change your name and, if you *really* want to, ask the team (team@stackexchange.com) to delete your account. It is however close to impossible to entirely anonymize your participation since that would require to modify/delete @replies by other users as well. It would be a shame to loose you as a valuable participant though!